# Prove that a function f is injective

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I will refer to Exercise 18 of Section 5.2 of Velleman's 2nd edition book. I am struggling proving the following:

Suppose $A,B,C$ are sets and $f: B\rightarrow C$. Suppose that $A\neq\varnothing$, and for all functions g and h from $A$ to $B$, if $f\circ g= f\circ h$ then $g=h$. Prove that $f$ is one-to-one.

I have tried two different approaches: 1) Using the assumptions just as they are, letting some $b,b'\in B$ and $f(b)=f(b')$ and trying to prove that $b=b'$. However, I don't see how to prove that, since I have the impression I need to know more about the functions $g$ and $h$. Since there is some $a\in A$, I used this to some function $g$ and $h$, but I don't really see how this helps me. 2) I tried proving by contradiction, but still think I need some functions $g$, $h$.

I would appreciate any hints/guide you could provide me as to how to proceed with this proof. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g:A\to B$ be the function that takes every element of $A$ to $b\in B$, i.e. $g(a)=b$ for all $a\in A$. Similarly, let $h:A\to B$ be defined as $h(a)=b'$ for all $a\in A$. Then we have shown injectivity by the first approach, that $f(b)=f(b')$ implies $b=b'$.

Comment: The important point about this problem is that the given information tells you that _for all $g$ and $h$_, something is true.  That means you can choose whatever you want for $g$ and $h$.  The key to QED's solutions was to make a good choice for $g$ and $h$.

Comment: Thanks. Definitley this is a very smart choice for both $g$ and $h$. I did know I needed one, but just couldn't come up with anything.